# Type conversion issue when using query dsl for nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

```
var products =
                this.productClient.Search<ProductSummaryModel>(s => s.From(startIndex).Size(pageSize).Query(q =>
                    {
                        QueryDescriptor<ProductSummaryModel> query = null;
                        if (productDetails.IsVisible.HasValue)
                        {
                            var productStatus = productDetails.IsVisible.Value
                                                    ? Constants.ProductStatus.Visible
                                                    : Constants.ProductStatus.Active;
                            query &= query.Term(p => p.Status, productStatus.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            query &= !q.Term(p => p.Status, Constants.ProductStatus.Deleted.ToString());
                        }

                        return query;
                    }));
```

I get the following errors.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Nest.BaseQuery' to 'Nest.QueryDescriptor'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Nest.BaseQuery' to 'Nest.QueryDescriptor'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Nest.SearchDescriptor' because it is not a delegate type

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Nest.BaseQuery' because it is not a delegate type

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm following the example at http://nest.azurewebsites.net/concepts/writing-queries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
QueryDescriptor<ProductSummaryModel> query = null;
```

to

```
BaseQuery query = null;
```

The docs are blatantly wrong here will update this ASAP!